# LDAP add entry above base dn

Tags: active-directory, ldap

My goal is to transfer entries from one ldap server to another - preserving the original base dn so that we do not have to modify the base dn reference on our mac os mail clients (we have hundreds).  Now granted, I realize we could go into each computer and change the dn, but we want to avoid this.

source: the LDAP that has the dn I want to preserve

target: the Active Directory LDAP I want to add the entry to

I can't seem to add entries above the base dn of target LDAP:

```
dn: dc=odmaster,dc=mhc,dc=org
dc: odmaster
objectclass: domain
```

The target LDAP currently has several entries below the dc=odmaster,dc=mhc,dc=org dn.

When I try imporing the following .ldif file via phpldapadmin I get the following error:
Could not add the object to the LDAP server server is unwilling to perform.  It doesn't work on the terminal via the ldapadd command either.

```
dn: ou=users,dc=mhc,dc=org
description: Users
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users
```

But it is successful when I add the entry below the base dn like this:

```
dn: ou=users,dc=odmaster,dc=mhc,dc=org
description: Users
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: users
```

Any idea why I cannot add entries at the dc=mhc,dc=org dn on the target LDAP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible answer is that the server database naming context is set to `dc=odmaster,dc=mhc,dc=org`. If this is the case, LDAP clients may not add entries above `dc=odmaster`. Check for this configuration by:

- consulting with the LDAP administrators
- consulting the root DSE programmatically

Another possibility is a access control that prevents clients from accessing, adding, or modifying entries.

#### See Also

- [The root DSE](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the link.  I ran the `ldapsearch` and the `namingContexts` returned as `dc=odmaster,dc=mhc,dc=org`.  Can I modify the root DSE by editing the `suffix` in the slapd.conf file - or is it more complicated then that?

Comment: this is the command I used:`ldapsearch -h thehostservername  -x -b '' -s base namingContexts`

Comment: No. LDAP clients may not modify `namingContexts`. This is defined as part of the configuration of the server, not to mention that it is an operational attribute.